# How to handle possible duplicates that treat the same thing but each a bit differently?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I was looking for coding style guidelines and came across a whole wealth of questions on the topic. It seems to me that they are somewhat redundant, although they discuss the topic from a slightly different angle each.

Here are the questions that I found:

- [Are there any coding style guidelines for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40775/are-there-any-coding-style-guidelines-for-latex)
- [Styleguide for LaTeX similar to the Google styleguides?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12171/styleguide-for-latex-similar-to-the-google-styleguides)
- [Writing readable LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86504/writing-readable-latex)
- [What are coding conventions in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95687/what-are-coding-conventions-in-latex)

What is the proper way of handling this? I think it would be better to have one central question on this, but then again, that won't happen. So tagging them as duplicates does not seem like the sane path to take.

Comment: imho, when you discuss something that doesn't exist, it is ok to be inconsistent. I would just let them be.

Comment: The _true_ problem of these questions is that they don't really fit in the scheme of a Q&A site: they are quite opinion-based, or too broad. This is not "I have this problem please help me" type of question, like things that would be in a reference book. This is more a "please guide me" type of quesion, and these simply don't work. The fact that they don't get closed is given by the fact that we simply tend not to close such questions; on the other hand, it's very difficult to make a canonical Q&A in such case.

Answer (score 2):

[SE BLog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/handling-duplicate-questions/)
Suggest that the community's response to "Borderline Duplicates" be to ensure that the tags match, so they show up in each others related `Related` Links.
Thus if someone is looking in one for an answer to a similar (but not identical ) problem, they will be able to look at the other similar questions

If they are true Duplicates they should be linked and closed, thus ensuring the asked gets the answetr they were seaking.
and if they are word for word Duplicates, they should be down voted and flagged (because that is someone gaming the system).

Comment: Great find. What would you recommend in this case?

Comment: How to write readable LaTeX, is substantially different, but i think it's tags could be improved alot.
The others, are different enough, I think they all count as boarderline.
It is too late now to close them, unless there is a mod tool to migrate answers across.